# Which Extension is suitable for my requriement for ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I am trying to Achive following

1) User is on Photo  Gallery

2) Select a photo

3) Hit Share

4) **Choose myapp( which i am developing)**

5) Need to show list of Categories ( **Will fetch from Sql Lite**)

6) Choose Category Name and Save that image into that category

Can you please guide me on the same. I had tried to implement Share Extension before. But not successful.

Comment: So you will finally save that photo in your app, under that category ? Is it ?

Comment: yes, i want to do this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use share extension and add a SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem
to your share extension for category name.

On click of category name show a list view with all possible options to choose category name and once user select one send image data and selected category name to server.

you can refer this links for more details

[Using an iOS 8 share extension to upload a photo to IBM Bluemix](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/ios-8-share-extension-photos-ibm-bluemix?lang=en)

[Sharing Extension](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/07/21/ios8-day-by-day-day-2-sharing-extension)